# How can I get full stage node log with Jenkins API?

Tags: jenkins

I tried to get log as written here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/tree/master/rest-api#get-jobjob-namerun-idexecutionnodenode-idwfapilog. But text in response presents only the end of the log, and parameter "hasMore" in response is true. How can I obtain the rest of log?

The corresponding endpoint in browser shows full log with flag `consoleFull`, but it didn't work for API.